# Generic Property Injection Using Autofac

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, autofac, dependency-properties

I have a generic class called BaseBL which is the abstract business logic class. All my BL classes inherit from this class. It has a property of type BaseDa which is another generic class.

```
public class BaseBl<T> : IBaseBl<T> where T : class
{
    public IBaseDa<T> BaseDa { get; set; }
}
```

How can I inject BaseDa property using Autofac?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you registering `IBaseDa<T>`? Where are you registering `BaseBl<T>`? What documentation have you read? Which other questions have you looked at?

Comment: What is the reason for the existence of this `BaseBl<T>` base class? What kind of logic is in it?